# Fast Range Detection Algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance

I have an Array of 8 elements: `Bin[8]`. 
Bin represents a range container: I receive a number `N`, such as `0 <= N <= 255`.

1. If `N < 32` ==> `Bin[0] += 1`
2. Else If `32 <= N < 64` ==> `Bin[1] += 1`
3. ... etc.

I want a fast solution that does not require an `If-Else` directive, as I have multiple Bins to handle.

I am using Java, but a solution in any programming language is accepted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure your number N is indeed 0 <= N <= 255, then simply:

```
Bin[N/32]++;
```

Edit: Another poster mentioned shifting right by 5 bits. This will work too, however I feel dividing by 32 shows intent cleaner and any modern compiler will optimize the division away into a bitshift if it's more efficient on the platform you're targeting anyway.

Answer (score 2):

We can use some bitwise operators for this:

```
binIndex = N >> 5;
```

Then

```
Bin[binIndex]++;
```

This just ignores the low 5 bits of the number, using the top three bits (if N <= 255) as an index into the array of bins.

Answer (score 1):

Just use integer division (truncation):

```
Bin[N / 32] += 1;
```

Comment: I know this question looks dumb ... aghh !! but I haven't slept in a while !!